# Swapping in assembly

Tags: assembly

I'm learning assembly and need to create 2 arrays. For the first one, I added 2 and then print the values. The second one I subtracted 2 and printed. These values came out right. When I try to swap the values, I get numbers values that are slightly off. Am I swapping wrong?

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096

.DATA

array1 DWORD 21H,22H,23H,24H,25H
array2 DWORD 31H,32H,33H,34H,35H

resultLbl1 BYTE "Array 1 values are",0
resultLbl2 BYTE "Array1 value1 is",0
resultLbl3 BYTE "Array1 value2 is",0
resultLbl4 BYTE "Array1 value3 is",0
resultLbl5 BYTE "Array1 value4 is",0
resultLbl6 BYTE "Array1 value5 is",0
string1 BYTE 40 DUP (?)
count DWORD 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC





       ;add 2 to array1 elements

       mov eax, array1
       add eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1

       mov eax, array1+4
       add eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1

       mov eax, array1+8
       add eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1

       mov eax, array1+12
       add eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1

       mov eax, array1+16
       add eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1


       ;subtract 2 from array2 elements


       mov eax, array2
       sub eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1

       mov eax, array2+4
       sub eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1

       mov eax, array2+8
       sub eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1

       mov eax, array2+12
       sub eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1

       mov eax, array2+16
       sub eax, 2
       dtoa string1, eax
       output resultLbl1, string1


       ;Swap array values in reverse


       mov eax, array2+16
       xchg array1, eax

       mov eax, array2+12
       xchg array1+4, eax

       mov eax, array2+8
       xchg array1+8, eax

       mov eax, array2+4
       xchg array1+12, eax

       mov eax, array2+4
       xchg array1+12, eax


       mov eax, array2
       xchg array1+16, eax

       mov eax, array1
       dtoa string1, eax

       output resultLbl2, string1

       mov eax, array1+4
       dtoa string1, eax

       output resultLbl3, string1


        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret
_MainProc ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your use of `xchg` is wrong. First because `xchg` writes to `eax` only for that value to be killed by the next instruction, and second because `xchg` with a memory argument has an (wasteful) implicit lock prefix.

You should use explicit temporaries instead:

```
mov eax, array1
mov edx, array2+16
mov array2+16, eax
mov array1, edx
```

The lines

```
mov eax, array2+4
xchg array1+12, eax
```

are also duplicated, which is suspicious.

Comment: The lock for xchg probably doesn't do anything unless a Xeon or other server cpu is being used that supports multiple processors that share a memory bus.

Comment: Hit return and didn't edit this quick enough. It's my understanding that the lock handshake logic is disabled or removed from Intel desktop processors. Intel desktop motherboards don't support it either. It seems unlikely that there's any extra "lock" overhead when using xchg on a desktop processor and motherboard.

Comment: The other case is if lock is used by multiple threads in a process or by multiple processes that share memory. Assuming this is a single threaded process, the lock should not cause any extra overhead.

Comment: From Intel's instruction reference manual: "If a memory operand is referenced, the processor’s locking protocol is automatically implemented for the duration of the exchange operation, regardless of the presence or absence of the LOCK prefix or of the value of the IOPL."

Comment: True, but there's no overhead or delay unless another thread or process is currently performing a locked memory access.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case, the atomic instructions are quite expensive.

Comment: I was going by some old article about xchg  / lock overhead, but it's outdated or it's just wrong. I changed the example code to use all mov instructions instead of xchg and it's about 14 times faster.

Comment: I used a better precision timer, make that 12.854 times faster.

Comment: Yep, that sounds about right (although I believe the performance hit varies a bit on different hardware).

Answer (score 0):

The program moves the array2 values into array1, but a second mov is needed to move the array1 values into array2. As pointed out by gsg, using xchg takes much longer than using mov, so I updated this code snippet to use mov.

```
    mov     eax,array2+16
    mov     edx,array1
    mov     array1,eax
    mov     array2+16,edx
    mov     eax,array2+12
    mov     edx,array1+4
    mov     array1+4,eax
    mov     array2+12,edx
    mov     eax,array2+8
    mov     edx,array1+8
    mov     array1+8,eax
    mov     array2+8,edx
    mov     eax,array2+4
    mov     edx,array1+12
    mov     array1+12,eax
    mov     array2+4,edx
    mov     eax,array2
    mov     edx,array1+16
    mov     array1+16,eax
    mov     array2,edx
```